# PHP malloc error with Zend Server CE 5.6.0 and WSO2 WSF/PHP

Tags: php, wso2, zend-server-ce

After upgrading from Zend Server Community Edition 5.5 to 5.6, PHP runs into malloc error when I try to connect to web services with WSO2 Web Services Framework for PHP.

The last line output in wsf_php_client.log is

```
[debug] (...)/wso2/2.1.0/scripts/dynamic_invocation/wsf_wsdl_util.php(1329) [WSF/PHP] importing xsd: (...) from: (...)
```

and the error thrown by PHP is

```
php(38384,0xa0ab0540) malloc: *** error for object 0x401bf61: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

The memory address 0xa0ab0540 seems to be consistent for every attempt.

Is there a way to figure out where the problem is to be found? Is it in the php executable, in the apache PHP module or can the problem be found in WSF/PHP itself?

Zend Server CE 5.6 runs PHP 5.3.9

```
PHP 5.3.9-ZS5.6.0 (cli) (built: Dec 22 2011 12:28:41)
```

Answer (score 0):

The malloc error seems to have had something to do with the WSF extension. After I rebuilt it from source, I got it working as intended. The only difference from previously was that I added `CC=clang CXX=clang` to the `./configure` command when compiling.

**Update:**
My conclusion was a bit premature. The malloc error occurs if I run WSF in WSDL-mode. If I send the SOAP envelope explicitly, I don't get the error. WSDL-mode worked fine when running on Zend Server CE 5.5.

Comment: In addition: I'm running it on Mac OS X 10.6.8.